# Change PDF Title when exporting

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a nice working PDF export VBA that I use to export a sheet in Excel.
The problem is that the title of the Workbook also is the title of the exported PDF.
I cannot seem to change the title upon export and I cannot find a working solution for this.

The titlename has to be dynamic as this will change for each export.

The filename can be different from titlename.

[Image found on internet shows the difference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Shb1.png) It is the title property that I want to change.

My export code shown below.

```
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim lOver As Long
Dim ary
Dim a As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler


Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\Monthly reports\"

strName = wsA.Range("V4").Value & "-" & wsA.Range("W4").Value & " " & wsA.Range("C5").Value _

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
  lOver = MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists")
  If lOver <> vbYes Then
    'user can enter name and
    ' select folder for file
    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
      (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
          FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
          Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
    If myFile <> "False" Then
      strPathFile = myFile
    Else
      GoTo exitHandler
    End If
  End If
End If

'Select sheets to use
ary = Array(Sheet5.Name)

For Each a In ary
    Sheets(a).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Next a

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select

'export to PDF in current folder
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strPathFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & strPathFile

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
```

Comment: do you want to be able to manually select the folder to export to and type the new name?

Comment: @kevin9999 The idea was to change the title of the document only. When I'm running above script it just saves the sheet as PDF. I want to change the title of the document to what I choose it to be.

Comment: OK.  I'm not sure if this will help at all, but I found https://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html online that _seems_ to give the option to name the file as you export it as a PDF.

Comment: Thank you :) The code in the link seems to be a lighter version of the script I use. I have an idea of changing the workbook title upon export and then change it back again in same script. When I have some time I'll look into it.